# How to use other ways to express the same meaning of a sentence?

Tags: american-english

I want to express the following  sentence in several other ways:

> The five flowers selected by using Method 2 is selected from the 10 flowers already selected by Method 1.

Can anyone give me some help? Thank you!

Comment: Ten flowers are selected by the first selection process; the second selection process further reduces the number to five.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, thank you ! any other way?

Comment: Method 2 selects 5 flowers from the 10 flowers selected by Method 1.

Comment: @Jim, can you see my update question?

Comment: We typically like to have posts with a single question in them. Since your second sentence is not related to the  first it should be in a separate question.  Having said that, what don’t you like about it?  It seems fine to me.

Comment: These both sound like sentences lifted from either a math lecture or math textbook.  Mathematicians' sentences are generally very carefully crafted---even if they do come across at times a bit clunky.  I think it would be better to pose this question on the math site instead of here if you want to be sure nothing gets lost in the paraphrasing.

Comment: @Jim,OK, I will post another question about the second setence.

Answer (score -3):

> From the 10 flowers selected in Method 1 is how the 5 flowers from Method 2 are selected.